# I need to add a lot of images to slideshow

Tags: html, slide

Sorry, but I am not a developer, my knowledge is limited to HTML and CSS. It is really a lot of time I'm spending to find a solution on the web and also here in the forum.

This is the example HTML to add images in HTML pages:

```
<div><img u="image" src="img/Chrysanthemum.jpg" /></div>
```

I am writing this manually, but if I have a lot of images to insert in the slideshow, how can I do to generate the html for all images?

Does exist any script to do this?

Comment: There are *a lot* of ways to do that. Do you want it server- or client-side? Any particular language? Are you already using something like a CMS or static site generator?

Comment: There is tool called [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/). It uses CSS abbreviations and expend them into HTML code. `div*100>img[u="image" src="img/Chrysanthemum$.jpg"]`.

Comment: the slideshow is handled by javascript. i suggest to use the client-side way (with javascript) to add images to the slideshow. By this, you don't have to run a serverside script. Which slideshow are you using, and how are the images being named ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use Emmet (http://Emmet.io) if it is supported by your editor/IDE to help with repetitive lines in HTML.

Otherwise you'll have to use some server scripting like PHP or nodejs.

Quick PHP example*:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php
       foreach(glob("images/slides/*") as $filename) {
           echo '<li><img src="'.$filename.'" alt=""/></li>';
       }
    ?>
</ul>
```

* not safe as "images/slides/*" may contain other files (not images), that are potentially not safe to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

One way using client-side script would be something like this (using jQuery):

```
var images = [
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum',
    'lorem-ipsum'
];

$.each(images, function( i, image ) {
    $('#your-container').append('<img u="image" id="image-'+i+'" src="img/'+image+'.jpg" />');
});
```

Replace the values in **images** array with your images names and finally replace the **$('#your-container')** with the your container selector.

Good luck!